# To fetch dialog property value selected by an author [AEM] in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, aem-6

I would like to know how to fetch selected value from a given dropdown by an author in **Touch UI dialog** using javascript for further manipulation.

Below is my dialog Structure

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs"
            type="nav"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <General
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                jcr:title="General Questions"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <layout
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <columns
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <allowed-selections
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
                                fieldLabel="Allowed Selections"
                                name="./allowed">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <one
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        text="One"
                                        value="one"/>
                                    <two
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        text="Two"
                                        value="two"/>
                                    <three
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        text="Three"
                                        value="three"/>
                                    <four
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        text="Four"
                                        value="four"/>
                                </items>
                            </allowed-selections>
                            <description/>
                            <selection-text
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"                               
                                fieldLabel="Selection Text"
                                name="./selectiontext"/>
                        </items>
                    </columns>
                </items>
            </General>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Here I would like to fetch dialog property value of ./allowed (dropdown) in my Javascript.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AEM is having one OOTB library to implement the hide/show feature.If you see the 
etc folder we have the below file

/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/dropdownshowhide/clientlibs/dropdownshowhide/js/dropdownshowhide.js

Foundationcontentloaded,changed and selected events are captured there based on the class name selector and target element select value is retrieved

See sample snippets

```
$(document).on("selected", ".dropdownselect", function(e) {
    //iterate over e and get element select value
});
```

$(element).data("select").getValue();

Add the class,dataattribute and selector as its given in the top of the js then you can get the selected dropdown value using the selected listener and do your custom logic

In your dialog add class dropdownselect and you can then capture value on change events

```
<allowed-selections
 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"sl
sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
 fieldLabel="Allowed Selections"
 name="./allowed"
class = "dropdownselect">
```

Comment: I'm not sure an absolute path is going to be useful to others in the future. You should expand a little on your solution so it can be understood in a general manner.

Comment: Sure. I was pointing to the default location in aem where we have this file. I will be updating the solution with some more inputs

Comment: I _guarantee_ you that someone down the road will _not_ have this file in this location, making this answer less useful to others. Not to mention that this location is only a default on some platforms. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer